# Use existing keypair for a new ec2 instance in CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

I want to use an existing keypair when creating my ec2 instance using CDK , but I can not find any clear reference on how this is done. I do know it is an InstanceProps.

The only item I seen on this site is in reference to a bastion host. this is not what I am trying to acheive.

This is the error I get....

[image]

How would I add reference to keyname: mykey

thanks for any help given!!

```
import ec2 = require('@aws-cdk/aws-ec2');



export class Ec2Stack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props) ;

// Look up VPC to use
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'vpc-0407979789789', {
  vpcName: 'vpc-my-test'
});
// Lookup Existing  SecurityGroup
const sg = ec2.SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(this, 'default', 'sg-06fea98uu9')

const instance = new ec2.Instance(this, 'Instance', {
  vpc: vpc,
  securityGroup: sg,
  KeyName: mykey,

  instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('t2.micro'),
  machineImage: new ec2.GenericLinuxImage({
    'us-west-2': 'ami-0e8c04af2729ff1bb'
  }),

});

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDK/CFn do not support EC2 keypair. Cannot create nor import/reference. Need to hard-code the keypair name.

- [Add ability to add EC2 key-pair #5252](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/5252)

Answer (score 0):

The PublicKeyMaterial property is used to import a key pair. If this property is not specified, then a new key pair will be created.

```
// The code below shows an example of how to instantiate this type.
// The values are placeholders you should change.
import { aws_ec2 as ec2 } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
const cfnKeyPair = new ec2.CfnKeyPair(this, 'MyCfnKeyPair', {
  keyName: 'keyName',

  // the properties below are optional
  keyFormat: 'keyFormat',
  keyType: 'keyType',
  publicKeyMaterial: 'publicKeyMaterial',
  tags: [{
    key: 'key',
    value: 'value',
  }],
});
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.CfnKeyPair.html